# Swift 3: Xcode claims that a non-generic class is generic

Tags: ios, generics, swift3

After converting to Swift 3 I'm having problems with visibility from Obj-C (Interface Builder can't find the controller class at runtime). So I added `@objc` to debug:

```
@objc(ASSitesTableViewController)
class ASSitesTableViewController : GenericFRCTableVC<Site>
```

And Xcode spits back:

> Generic subclasses of '@objc' classes cannot have an explicit '@objc' attribute because they are not directly visible from Objective-C

But the class isn't really generic. It only inherits from a class that has been specialized.

I'm aware that subclassing a specialized type is a long shot since it hasn't been supported in earlier versions of Swift, but it compiled without complaints. I did not expect my class to *stay* generic.

I found no mention of generics in the inheritance section of the Swift docs, or vice-versa.

Does the base class have to be non-generic for the subclass to be visible to Obj-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the base class have to be non-generic for the subclass to be visible to Obj-C?

Yes. The subclass does not itself have a generic placeholder in its definition, but a subclass "is" its superclass. A Dog "is" a Quadruped (if Dog is a subclass of Quadruped). So this class "is" a `GenericFRCTableVC<Site>`. Well, Objective-C can make no sense of a `GenericFRCTableVC<Site>` so it can make no sense of an ASSitesTableViewController.

> After converting to Swift 3

I think you'll find you would have had the same problem in an earlier version of Swift. I don't believe this has anything to do with the conversion to Swift 3.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. The bigger problem arose because of Swift 3 since the FRC (fetched results controller) was made generic in that version, which I unsuccessfully tried to propagate down the chain.

Comment: I know - I've had a number of difficulties with the new imported generics. However, keep in mind that imported generics _are covariant_ on the parametrized type. That can help in a lot of situations.

Comment: All of them? Sounds more like breaking type safety than a feature, but I could not find documentation of that behavior. I think ordinary arrays behaved like that too until Swift 2. https://youtu.be/n9yAJfYjcl4?t=39m6s